# Why does my internet randomly turn off?

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

It seems to turn off yet still show I'm connected.  I did a ping and it shows no addresses are found.  I did an ipconfig with the wifi on and this is what I got:

```
enp12s2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0b:97:bd:08:6a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:540 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:540 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:44903 (44.9 KB)  TX bytes:44903 (44.9 KB)

wlp11s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:d2:ad:11:79  
          inet addr:10.0.0.14  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cff7:9d47:b48d:2593/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6336 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9296196 (9.2 MB)  TX bytes:888777 (888.7 KB)
```

and here are the results for lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; iwconfig

```
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection [8086:1000]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
    Kernel modules: iwl3945
0c:00.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II [1180:0476] (rev b4)
--
0c:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Matsushita Electric Industrial Co., Ltd. Panasonic CF-Y5 laptop [10f7:8338]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
    Kernel modules: 8139cp, 8139too
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp11s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Sudbrook"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 04:A1:51:17:74:E2   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:130   Missed beacon:0

enp12s2   no wireless extensions.
```

If anyone could help that would be awesome!

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; iwconfig`

Comment: Okay, I just corrected it all, does anyone know the diagnosis?